# How to auto assign public ip to EC2 instance with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I have to start a new machine with `ec2.run_instances` in a given subnet but also to have a public ip auto assigned (not fixed elastic ip).

When one starts a new machine from the Amazon's web EC2 Manager via the Request Instance (Instance details) there is a check-box called **Assign Public IP** to Auto-assign Public IP.
See it highlighted in the screenshot:

[image: Request Instance wizard]

How can I achieve that check-box functionality with `boto`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<s>Interestingly enough, seems that not many people had this problem.</s> For me was very important to be able to do this right. Without this functionality one is not able to reach out to the internet from instances that are launched into a `nondefault subnet`.

The boto documentation provided no help, there was a related bug recently fixed, see at: https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/1705.

It's important to note that the `subnet_id` and the security `groups` have to be provided to the network interface `NetworkInterfaceSpecification` instead of `run_instance`.

```
import time
import boto
import boto.ec2.networkinterface

from settings.settings import AWS_ACCESS_GENERIC

ec2 = boto.connect_ec2(*AWS_ACCESS_GENERIC)

interface = boto.ec2.networkinterface.NetworkInterfaceSpecification(subnet_id='subnet-11d02d71',
                                                                    groups=['sg-0365c56d'],
                                                                    associate_public_ip_address=True)
interfaces = boto.ec2.networkinterface.NetworkInterfaceCollection(interface)

reservation = ec2.run_instances(image_id='ami-a1074dc8',
                                instance_type='t1.micro',
                                #the following two arguments are provided in the network_interface
                                #instead at the global level !!
                                #'security_group_ids': ['sg-0365c56d'],
                                #'subnet_id': 'subnet-11d02d71',
                                network_interfaces=interfaces,
                                key_name='keyPairName')

instance = reservation.instances[0]
instance.update()
while instance.state == "pending":
    print instance, instance.state
    time.sleep(5)
    instance.update()

instance.add_tag("Name", "some name")

print "done", instance
```

Comment: Anyone get this error while doing this? `The associatePublicIPAddress parameter cannot be specified for a network interface with an ID.`

Comment: yes, apparently you can't create the interface first any more if you want a public IP. I'll add an answer for boto3 which reflects this. [oh wait, I don't have to. see barryku's]

Answer (score 8):

boto3 has NetworkInterfaces you can configure for DeviceIndex=0, and the Subnet and SecurityGroupIds should be moved from instance level to this block instead.  Here's a working version for me,

```
def launch_instance(ami_id, name, type, size, ec2):
   rc = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId=ami_id,
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    KeyName=key_name,
    InstanceType=size,
    NetworkInterfaces=[
        {
            'DeviceIndex': 0,
            'SubnetId': subnet,
            'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
            'Groups': sg
        },
    ]
   )

   instance_id = rc[0].id
   instance_name = name + '-' + type
   ec2.create_tags(
    Resources = [instance_id],
    Tags = [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': instance_name}]
   )

   return (instance_id, instance_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with this feature myself, but the `run_instances` call has a parameter called `network_interfaces`. According to the [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.networkinterface.NetworkInterfaceSpecification) you can give IP address detailes there.

Comment: Indeed one has to use network_interfaces, but sadly the documentation wasn't helpful, I ended up reading the code and the amazon ec2 API.